# ¿Deberíamos permitir usuarios que solo editan?

Tags: discusión, ediciones, usuarios

He visto usuarios, y no pocos, que solo se dedican a editar y se  ganan la reputación así.

La cosa es que en su mayoría solo corrigen faltas ortográficas pero también hay veces que corrigen código sin saber el mas mínimo sobre este.

La cosa es si deberíamos bloquear las ediciones a usuarios que tengan un mínimo de puntuación en esas etiquetas.

No me gusta dar ejemplos pero si son necesarios para tirar adelante la moción los pondré.

Comment: Hay un limite de reputación que pueden ganar editando.

Comment: Editar es una cosa que en general y esencialmente veo como positiva. Como todo, si se hace incorrectamente debe revisarse. Tenemos una gran herramienta que es el historial de revisiones de una publicación, que nos permite volver atrás si el cambio fue pernicioso. Y en casos que se agravan, uno puede reportar al usuario para que un moderador lo gestione. Creo que iría bien algún ejemplo para ver más claramente a qué te refieres.

Comment: Como dice @EmanuelVe, hay un límite, que son 1000 puntos, pero doné el doble con recompensas. Lo que por un lado viene, por el otro se va.

Comment: También es verdad que a veces editar no es de ayuda: uno debe pulir diamantes, no piedras :)

Comment: @fedorqui sin duda, no pretendía decir que editar una pregunta es malo, me refiero a la gente que no lo usa para el bien

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ya se está *bloqueando* la libre edición ya que con baja reputación, las ediciones pasan por una [cola de revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits). 
Es ahí donde se aprueba si el edit es válido.

Generalmente **rechazo** aquellas que editan código porque van contrarias a la idea del autor incluso si el edit es para arreglar un fallo mínimo como `console.log` en vez de `consol.log` ya que puede estar ahí el problema y tras el edit **no saber que le pasa al OP**.

Si el codigo tiene un problema **tipografico** se debe hablarlo en los comentarios con el autor, para que esté al corriente de ese problema y tras eso, editarlo si así se ha **consensuado**.

Pero para nada debe cambiarse un `for loop` por un `for each` porque  *te guste más* ese bucle. Para eso no es la edición de publicaciones.

Yo siempre quito aquellas partes (generalmente al principio y al final) que son **comentarios subjetivos** y personales: "buenos dias", "hola como estan", "soy nuevo en esta tecnologia", ... y también arreglo **el formato**: párrafos, negrita, bloques de codigo, nombres de variables, tags, citas, puntos, comas, enumeraciones e indentación.

Y si el codigo es `JS/HTML` lo incluyo en un snippet (tras comprobar que su código es válido y se puede ejecutar) para que los usuarios puedan probarlo.

---

Respecto a la reputación, hay un máximo que puedes ganar con las ediciones y no creo que sea un motivo por el que la gente edita publicaciones.

Comment: Otro debate interesante es si a veces aprobamos ediciones que son tan mínimas que tampoco ayudan demasiado. Es decir, creo que la gente debería llenar la cola de sugerencias de edición cuando tenga cosas sustanciales a modificar; de lo contrario, me parece que está usando el tiempo de los revisores tontamente y sería mejor que esperaran a hacer esas ediciones cuando tengan suficiente reputación para que no pasaran por la cola. [Ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/46986)

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. Las mejoras facilitan la lectura, y en ocasiones, la edición de ciertos títulos pueden tener un efecto positivo para el que pregunta. Como bien apuntas al final, desconozco el límite, pero no creo que nadie se plantee ganar 1k editando...

Comment: @OscarR si, y no solo la facilidad de lectura. A veces ves un unico parrafo que ni te dan ganas de leer. una vez separado por partes , con listas o parrafos, creo que uno es más reacio a leerla. La calidad del formato es importante en la calidad general de la pregunta

Comment: @lois6b cierto es que algunas preguntas/respuestas no se arreglan ni con formato... dentro de las limitaciones que tenemos para ayudar, se intenta que no se _achicharre_ los ojos alguien que lo encuentre, ya sea de SOes o que lo encuentre en algún buscador.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, tu caso lo conozco ya que has editado un par de preguntas mias, y sin ningún problema buenas ediciones, pero mi caso mas grave me paso ayer cuando volví de trabajar me encontré con 5 ediciones seguidas en la cola, y no podía rechazarlas o aceptarlas porque eran de gente con reputación y solo cambiaban título o algo menor incluso corrigiendo otra ediciones anteriores

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez ¿por qué no podías rechazarlas? Todos somos iguales ante las colas y ante todo en este sitio. Si alguien proponee una edición poco útil según tú, recházala independientemente de la reputación que tenga.

Comment: @fedorqui no se como van las ediciones, se que por algún motivo algunas puedo rechazarlas mientras que otras se editan automáticamente, y luego será que no estoy viendo el modo de volver atrás

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez cuando dos personas coinciden en el diagnóstico, se aplica. Así, si das a "rechazar", votas en contra de ella. Si otra persona la rechaza, quedará rechazada. Si dos personas votan luego a favor, queda aceptada.

Comment: Muy útil esta respuesta @lois6b.